# jquery Mobile Form is not submitting after change event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm doing Jquery Mobile Application with single form.I type some text in textarea and renamed submit button with a new name after completely typing texts.The form is not submitting at the first press.Its only submitting, second time I press the submit button.But I need to submit the form at the first press.Tested from my Android Mobile.Here is the code,

```
        <div id="pg_send-sms" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <form name="frm_send-sms" id="frm_send-sms" action="" method="post">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme='b'>
                <h1 id='send-sms-header'></h1>
                <a href="#pg_home" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                <a href="" data-role='button' id="history_redirect" data-icon="grid">History</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" id="pg_send-sms_content" class='center-wrapper'>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="txt_msg_box" style="text-align: left;">Message</label>
                <textarea name="txt_msg_box" class="txt_msg_box" id="txt_msg_box" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div  data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <input type="submit" name="btn_send_submit" id="btn_send_submit" value="Send" data-theme='b' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme='b'>
                <h1 id="send-sms-footer"></h1>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    sendsms.js
    $( "#pg_send-sms" ).on( "pagecreate", function( event ) {

        $('.txt_msg_box').change(changebuttonText);
    });

    function changebuttonText() {   

        $('#btn_send_submit').val("Message");
        $('#btn_send_submit').button("refresh");   
    }
    $("#btn_send_submit").click(function(e){
          alert('button clicked');
          return false;
    });
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1c1g9zpv/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Just Wrapp the code inside an `.ready(function(){})` doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_send_submit").click(function(e){
      if($("#btn_send_submit").val("send")){
         $('#btn_send_submit').val("Message");
         $('#btn_send_submit').button("refresh"); 
         alert("im in")
        }
       return false;
       });
    });
```

Test this code by your own, or in the JFiddle, on the `FrameWork and Extension` section, select from `<no wrap - in 'body'>` to  `<onLoad>` option, also i try to clean a little bit the code, remove the function and replace by an `if statement`

Comment: Its submitting well but the button text is not changed.

Comment: Check the edit on the answer, works for me tell me if works for you